# Analog of BeanPropertySqlParameterSource that can handle public fields

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I have a simple model, instances of which I want to save in MySQL using Spring JDBCTemplate. I use DAO that saves model objects using simple sql (`insert into user(id, email...) value (:id, :email...)`). Is there any framework that can extract parameters from the model (when the model is just POJO with public fields). So, I need something similar to Spring's `BeanPropertySqlParameterSource`, but with the ability to work with public fields instead of properties.

Example of the model class:

```
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String email;
    public String login;
    public String password;
}
```

I know that extending `AbstractSqlParameterSource` can solve my problem, but I hope to find existing framework.

**UPD**

Implementation based on `AbstractSqlParameterSource`:

```
public class PublicFieldsSqlParameterSource extends AbstractSqlParameterSource {

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    public PublicFieldsSqlParameterSource(Object object) {
        Field[] fields = object.getClass().getFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            String name = field.getName();
            try {
                Object value = field.get(object);
                props.put(name, value);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasValue(String paramName) {
        return props.containsKey(paramName);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String paramName) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        return props.get(paramName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The existing framework is called JavaBeans. Add public accessors for your fields and then you'll be able to use libraries naturally. That is the purpose of coding conventions.

Comment: @SkinnyJ of course I know about JavaBeans, but their universality is [questionable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters). I believe using public fields will be perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reason for not adding getters/setters to your User class? Is it an existing API? If not and the reason is not to have the getters/setters pollute your class, my recommendation would be using lombok: https://projectlombok.org/ for generating accessors. We are using Lombok extensively with Spring and it can remove much of the code that is just there for convention, but reduces readability of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in my comment if the reason for not wanting getter/setters is code clutter, I would recommend [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/).

Here is a typical model class, that can be constructed by Spring (`@NoArgsConstructor` + `@Data` for getters and setters). `@Builder` and `@AllArgsConstructor` allow the generation of the Builder pattern with all fields.

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SubscriptionData {

    @Id
    @Indexed
    private UUID key;

    private String productId;

    private String receiptString;

    private Date expirationDate;

}
```

Here is an example of a Spring service with constructor injection. The `@RequiredArgsConstructor` creates a constructor with all the non-initialized final fields and the onConstructor parameter adds the Spring-`@Autowired` annotation to it. If you have many service-dependencies this can remove quite some clutter.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__({ @Autowired }))
public class OperatorServiceImpl implements OperatorService {

  private final WhoisService whoisService;

  ...
}
```

Comment: You did not answer the question per se, but your answer is the most helpful one. Using Lombok I can avoid boilerplate code and use regular `BeanPropertyRowMapper`.